# Is Software Generated Interrupt (SGI) an synchronous exception on ARMv8?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, interrupt, cortex-m, armv8

I am trying to write a bare metal application on an ARMv8 board. When I signal a SGI, the exception type of the SGI is synchronous while I am expecting it to be either FIQ or IRQ. Can I config it to be an IRQ? Or could someone explain to me why it is synchronous?

Comment: Synchronous just means 'when' it is delivered.  It really won't matter too much to you.  An asynchronous interrupt can happen any time, even while an instruction is executing.  The SGI will onl y happen at the end of an instruction.

Comment: "I am expecting it to be either FIQ or IRQ", why ??? like really what are you trying to archive by that ?

Comment: @artlessnoise That makes sense. SGI is synchronous because it is generated by the execution flow. I was thinking that a SGI shouldn't be synchronous if it is triggered by an asynchronous interrupt, but it is essentially triggered by the interrupt handler code which fits into the definition of synchronous interrupts.

Comment: @user3124812 Sorry for not making it clear. I was confused by the kind of SGI triggered by asynchronous interrupts, so I thought an IRQ triggered SGI is still an IRQ since it is not predictable, but that's not the definition of synchronous interrupts.